# Collection with no duplicates and in order

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I need a `Collection` that contains no duplicates and the items are in order.
I know `hashSet` contains a set with no duplicates. But items in a set are in no specific order.

What alternative do I have? Are there any built-in list in `.Net` that can be used in `c# programming` language?

EDIT: 
**The set must also be an observable**

I need to use this set to work with **WPF** in **MVVM** principles.
any `observablecollection sortedset?`

Comment: Linq toObjects? [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)

Comment: how would you define "in order"?  The order which they were added, alphabetized by some property, etc...

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: make an answer out of it. But was not so difficult to find for OP, was it?

Comment: @Jonesopolis: read the remarks section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411709(v=vs.110).aspx (also the class remarks state: _"Duplicate elements are not allowed"_)

Comment: @Jonesopolis: all classes that implement [`ISet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd412081(v=vs.100).aspx) have unique elements.

Comment: @ Mark Shevchenko I have updated my question. Can you please look at it again.

Comment: @RayOldProf maybe [this link](http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/14/write-a-sortable-observablecollection-for-wpf/) useful for you.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei this solution is very inefficient. the sortedList have o(1), with this solution it will be o(n). I think there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

[Sorted set](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sortedset) might be the collection you're looking for.

> SortedSet is an ordered set collection. We have many elements and want
>   to store them in a sorted order and also eliminate all duplicates from
>   the data structure. The SortedSet is part of the
>   System.Collections.Generic namespace.